# Ajax web part does not work in Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint-2007

I have an AJAX web part which is working properly in my local windows 7 environment, but when I deployed in the real environment which is running win server 2003, it doesn't work as I expected. Does anybody have an idea to resolve this? I am using MOSS 2007

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly provide the error details or your implementation

Comment: I don't receive any error when I import the web part to the default page, but let me give some implementation details...

I have a custom master page to which I add my custom web parts..
this problematic web part just contain a text box and a button for searching the site. I created it using AJAX and when I hit the search button it correctly displays the search results, but that's all, after that I cannot search, when I hit the button again and again, it doesn't respond and remain in the last view, but this exact web part work fine in my local machine????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem to the situation. It was a matter mismatch between my development environment and the real deployment environment..

Btw thanks for your input as well...

Best Regards,
Asanka